# Split string into multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've a dataset similar to the one below (there are more columns but just using these for example purposes).

| PersonId | LocationId | StartDate | AttendanceString |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-01 | XXXXZZZZ######PPLL |
| 234 | 678 | 2018-10-01 | PPPPLL######ZZZZXX |

What I need to achieve is split the *AttendanceString* column into multiple rows and multiple columns. The attendance string needs to be broken down every 2 characters and split into 2 different columns, representing a morning and afternoon period. An example will make this clearer so let's use the first record. The desired outcome is:

| PersonId | LocationId | StartDate | MorningAttendanceString | AfternoonAttendanceString |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-01 | X | X |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-02 | X | X |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-03 | Z | Z |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-04 | Z | Z |
| 123 | 987 | 2018-09-05 | # | # |

For each string, we need to iterate until we reach the last character, adding new records into a table corresponding to a different day and with separate records for morning/afternoon.

I'm able to achieve the desired logic with the code at the end of this post. However, because this may involve about 90/100k records and most of them will need to be broken into 365 records, we're talking about 33-35M records that need to be created. I'm using a cursor with a while cycle to get these results and even though cursors are normally to be avoided, I don't really think it's the issue here. This normally takes about 30mins to run on an Azure SQL Database in a S6 Standard Tier.

Is there any option I'm missing to make this more efficient? Ideally I'd like to reduce the time it takes to process the data. I can't really use split_string since it expects a specific character used to break the string.

```sql
DECLARE @LocationID as int;
DECLARE @AttendanceString as varchar(1000);
DECLARE @StartDate as date;
DECLARE @PersonId as int;

DECLARE @MorningValue as char(1);
DECLARE @AfternoonValue as char(1);

DECLARE @DayDate as date;
DECLARE @AttendanceCursor as cursor;

DECLARE @i as int;

SET @AttendanceCursor = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 
    PersonId,
    LocationId, 
    StartDate, 
    AttendanceString
FROM 
    SourceTable
WHERE 
    StartDate >= '2019-08-01'

BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    OPEN @AttendanceCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @AttendanceCursor INTO @PersonId , @AttendanceString, @StartDate, @LocationId;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @i = 1;
        SET @DayDate = @StartDate;

        WHILE (@i < len(@AttendanceString))
        BEGIN
            SET @MorningValue = SUBSTRING(@AttendanceString,@i,1);
            SET @AfternoonValue = SUBSTRING(@AttendanceString,@i+1,1);
            
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO FinalTable
                SELECT @DayDate , @LocationId, @PersonId, @MorningValue @AfternoonValue
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
               ...
            END CATCH
            
            SET @i = @i+2;
            SET @DayDate = DATEADD(DD,1,@DayDate );
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @AttendanceCursor INTO @PersonId , @AttendanceString, @StartDate, @LocationId;

    END  

    CLOSE @AttendanceCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @AttendanceCursor ;
```

Comment: Is the length of `AttendanceString` always fixed or is it variable?

Comment: The cursor solution just finished in 1 hour 26 minutes on the same server.  The `SELECT ...INTO` finishes in 2 seconds on my server.  This looks like a significant improvement to me.

Comment: It's not fixed, it can have different lengths, normally around 730 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote this as a set based query instead of a cursor and this *whole* script, including the generation of 100k test records runs in about 40 seconds on my Azure SQL DB, which is a Serverless gen 5 with only 1 vCore.  Work through the script to make sure you understand it.

NB I'm dropping the tables as this is a test rig - not production code:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Setup START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.sourceTable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.finalTable
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.sourceTable
(
    PersonId            INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    LocationId          INT,
    StartDate           DATE,
    AttendanceString    VARCHAR(1000)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.finalTable
(
    DayDate         DATE, 
    LocationId      INT, 
    PersonId        INT, 
    MorningValue    CHAR(1), 
    AfternoonValue  CHAR(1)
)
GO

-- Generate some test data
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.sourceTable ON

INSERT INTO dbo.sourceTable ( PersonId, LocationId, StartDate, AttendanceString )
VALUES
    ( 123, 987, '2018-09-01', 'XXXXZZZZ######PPLL' ),
    ( 234, 678, '2018-10-01', 'PPPPLL######ZZZZXX' ),
    ( 567, 999, '2018-10-01', 'abcdefghijklmnopqr' )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.sourceTable OFF
GO

-- Setup END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test Data START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 rn, 1 locationId, CAST( '1 Jan 2018' AS DATE ) startDate, REPLACE( NEWID(), '-', '' ) AttendanceString
UNION ALL
SELECT rn + 1, rn % 42, DATEADD( day, 1, startDate ), REPLACE( NEWID(), '-', '' )
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 100
)
INSERT INTO dbo.sourceTable ( LocationId, StartDate, AttendanceString )
SELECT LocationId, StartDate, AttendanceString 
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1;
GO 1000


-- Test Data END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Rewritten query START
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp;

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 n, 1 x, 2 y
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1, x + 2, y + 2
FROM cte
WHERE n < 20
)
SELECT
    personId,
    locationId,
    DATEADD( day, c.n - 1, startDate ) xdate,
    SUBSTRING ( attendanceString, c.x, 1 ) a,
    SUBSTRING ( attendanceString, c.y, 1 ) b

INTO #tmp

FROM dbo.sourceTable s
    CROSS APPLY cte c
WHERE c.y <= LEN(attendanceString);


select *
from sourceTable
WHERE personId = 999

select *
from #tmp
WHERE personId = 999

select *
from #tmp
WHERE locationId = 999

-- Rewritten query END
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Altered version of the script for longer attendanceIds [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/7588e74e1046ef5a016c0140f46df525).

Comment: Thanks for this wBob, I understand what you did here and why you were asking about the length of the strings. Will need to adjust the number of numbers generated in the cte since they are a bit bigger but will give this a go and update with the results

Comment: Worked like a charm wBob, 34M rows processed in 2m30s. Makes me hang my head in shame if I compare it to what I had!

Comment: Good stuff.  I've added an altered test rig which extends the length of the attendance strings to 960 and splits off the creation of the map table which I think would be a good idea.  Please do some testing to ensure that the new solution functionally does the same as the old one.  At least you've got old results and new ones to test as a comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I tested before coming back to you. This is a huge improvement over what I had and, as I said, makes me look bad considering my initial approach :)

Comment: Cool, don't be afraid to upvote as well!  : )   Can you confirm the original run time as well please?  So it used to take say 1 hour and now it takes 2 mins 30, something like that?

Comment: Can't upvote yet, need more reputation points to do that. The original run time, for about 93k records transformed into about 33-34M records would take ~30mins. Your first approach takes about 2m/2m30s and if split the creation of the map table, it goes down to 1m30s